# How to change Listening port of Hyper Ledger Composer Playground?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I need to change hyper ledger composer playground listening port.

On the [documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/using-playground-locally.html) shows how install Hyperledger Playground locally, but not how to start, stop and change listening port.

Comment: To stop playground, just press **ctrl + c** (windows) or **cmd + c** (mac).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways to change the port, either using the `-p` option for example

```
composer-playground -p 9090
```

or you can export an environment variable

```
$ export PORT=9090
$ composer-playground
```